# maintaining user input when displaying and clearing error msg in fieldset field

Tags: javascript, php

When I want to convey an error message to the user regarding their input, I would like to inform them of the error but keep all field values already filled out/selected maintained. Although this is possible using a js alert box, the php page is not visible beneath the alert box until the alert is acknowledge and the alert box is just plain ugly.

Instead I would prefer to use something like:

```
echo "<fieldset id='fieldsetErr'>
              <legend id='legendErr'>Error:</legend>
              <p id='pErr'>" . $errMsg . "
              <br><br>
              <span style='padding-left:200px'>
                <a href='searchCriteria.php'>
                  <button>Clear</button>
                </a>
              </span>
              </p>
              </fieldset>";
```

with CSS something like:

```
#fieldsetErr {
  width: 500px;
  background:
    url(images/logo.jpg)
    top center / 300px 300px
    no-repeat
    fixed
    padding-box
    content-box
    red;
  color: white;
}

#legendErr {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px black, 0 0 25px red, 0 0 5px red;
}

#pErr {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

This fieldset error message integrates nicely with the rest of the page's layout. Unfortunately when the "Clear" button is click of course a new instance of the searchCriteria.php is loaded and all the user's previous input is lost.

If I simply remove the Clear button and so the option to clear the error message, the user's input values are still maintained while they can make necessary corrections and re-submit. But is it possible to let the user clear the fieldset error message away after they have read it without clearing away all the values they have input to that point, if so how might it be done?

**UPDATE:**

I thought maybe I could do what I want by wrapping the fieldset error message in div tags:

```
echo '<div id="divErr">
              <fieldset id="fieldsetErr">
                  <legend id="legendErr">Error:</legend>
                  <p id="pErr">' . $errMsg . '
                  <br><br>
                  <span style="padding-left:200px">                    
                    <button onclick=<script type="text/javascript">','removeDivErr();','</script>>Clear</button>
                  </span>
                  </p>
              </fieldset>
            </div>';
```

and using a js function to remove the fieldset element when the Clear button is clicked:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function removeDivErr() {
      var elem = document.getElementById('divErr');
      elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
    }
  </script>
```

Although it does not work as pasted, I am uncertain whether or not it is because of the way I am trying to call/integrate the javascript into the php echo statement. I have tried quoting the php echo statement and javascript function call in different ways to see if I could coax it to work, but so far nadda. Can anybody confirm?

Comment: I think you need to take an ajax approach to do this, not just php.